# Deleting one specific list-object from db

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb

Im having trouble with what should be a simple task in RavenDB.
In know how to delete a document in Raven in this manner

```
Session.Delete("Artist/1")
```

Now, Im not looking to delete the entire document. I only want to delete one of the
list-objects in `"Album`".

```
Id: Artist/1
  "Artist": 
  "Image": "imgOfArtist",

  "Album": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "Title": ""
      "AlbumCover": "linkToCover"
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "Title": ""
      "AlbumCover": "linkToCover"
    }
  ],
```

How can this be done? It seem to me that a good start is to load the document like this:

```
var theDoc = Session.Load<AllArtists>("Artist/1");
```

Then maybe i Should do something like this:

```
var Todelete = theDoc.Albums.Where(o => o.Id == 1);

Session.Delete(Todelete);
```

This gives me the following error:
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[XXXXXXXXX.Albums] is not associated with the session, cannot delete unknown entity instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just remove the document value.

```
var artist = Session.Load<AllArtists>("artists/1");
artists.Albums.RemoveAt(3);
Session.SaveChages();
```